# Python parsing xml/opf file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

i want to read the entry between

```
<dc:title> </dc:title>
```

This is xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" version="2.0" unique-identifier="calibre-uuid">
<metadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:calibre="http://calibre.kovidgoyal.net/2009/metadata" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<meta name="calibre:series_index" content="1"/>
<dc:language>UND</dc:language>
<dc:creator opf:file-as="Unbekannt" opf:role="aut">Johann Wolfgang von Goethe</dc:creator>
<meta name="calibre:timestamp" content="2009-10-08T07:26:21"/>
<dc:title>Faust_I_</dc:title>
<meta name="cover" content="cover"/>
<dc:date>2009-10-08T07:26:21</dc:date>
<dc:contributor opf:role="bkp">calibre (0.6.13) [http://calibre-ebook.com]</dc:contributor>
<dc:identifier id="calibre-uuid">urn:uuid:3cd4b26f-39a3-4783-9730-a86c26b30818</dc:identifier>
```

And that's my code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('content.opf')
root = tree.getroot()
dc_namespace = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
print (root.attrib[ET.QName(dc_namespace, 'title')])
```

Output Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PythonApplication1\Modul1.py", line 8, in <module>
print (root.attrib[ET.QName(dc_namespace, 'title')])
KeyError: <QName '{xmlns:dc}title'>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: what is your current error/output?

Comment: Added Output Error.

Comment: A couple of end tags are missing in your XML.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for (`<dc:title>`) is an element, not an attribute. Here is how you can get its value:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('content.opf')
title = tree.find(".//{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}title")
print(title.text)
```

Output:

```
Faust_I_
```

Relevant references:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax

Comment: Thanks.  But how do I read the content property of a meta tag given its name property?

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
root[number][number]
```

to access the elements.
for example in

```
<base>
   <element1>
       <element2>asdada</element2>
   </element>
</base>
```

root[0][0] will give u element 2

Comment: Yes, i used this before but it isn't everytime the same element number but everytime the same tag (<dc:title> </dc:title>)

Comment: You can use minidom.